# Can anyone recommend twitter client that support sock5 proxy?

Tags: proxy, twitter

I have already tried gwibber,twitux, destroy twitter,smuxi,gtwitter,choqok,qwit and hotot.

only hotot could configured sock5 proxy but not all traffic over sock5 (I captured packets using wireshark and I found images link not be included.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All programs can use sock5 if you use `tsocks`. They don't even have to know they're doing it.

Install [tsocks](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/tsocks/), configure `/etc/tsocks.conf`, start up your socks tunnel, or whatever, and then launch your favourite client like this:

```
tsocks gwibber
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try Polly. I believe it supports SOCK5 proxy from what I can see from the preferences but I haven't tried it personally.

To install Polly, you need to add the PPA. You can try the following commands in a terminal to install Polly.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:conscioususer/polly-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install polly
```

[image]

Relevant link:

- [OMG!Ubuntu! | New Pre-Alpha of Twitter App Polly Available](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/10/pre-alpha-twitter-app-polly/)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 and that repository show an error. W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/conscioususer/polly-unstable/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

Comment: @smile Polly is only available for 11.04 and later releases. Sorry about that.